# why Isn't python remembering the value of my variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a function that stores where the mouse was when I press the s key, and I created another function that prints the locations that I stored, but the problem is, when I run the second function it gives me this error: `NameError: name 'coords' is not defined`. My code is below.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as py
import keyboard
root = tk.Tk()
def func1():
    coords = []
    while True:  # making a loop
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
            coords+=py.position()
            time.sleep(0.4)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
            break
def func2():
    print(coords)

B = tk.Button(root, text='hello world', width=20, command=func1)
B.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

C = tk.Button(root, text='hello', width=20, command=func2)
C.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func2` doesn't have access to the variables that are "local" to `func1`.

`func1` needs to return the coordinate values and then pass them to `func2` as an argument.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Or use a global. Declare `coords` outside both functions, and use `global coords` inside the functions to bring that name into scope. This is normally a terrible idea on the long run, but can be a useful tool for quick throwaway code.

Comment: Here's an (untested) example of using arguments: https://gist.github.com/pkoch/4997a8b3a54a4cb0ab75b34148d774bf HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `coords = []` outside the function `func1()` to `func2` be able to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

`coords` is a local variable of `func1`, and as such `func2` is unaware of its existence.
You could add `return coords` at the end of `func1`, and start off `func2` with the line `coords = func1()`. Point is, you must define a variable called `coords` in `func2` first.

Another option would be making `coords` a global variable in the first place. e.g:

```
coords = []
def func1():
   ...

def func2():
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared inside a function so it is unreachable for function 2.
Try out the below code:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as py
import keyboard

root = tk.Tk()

coords = []

def func1():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            coords+=py.position()
            time.sleep(0.4)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
            break
def func2():
    print(coords)

B = tk.Button(root, text='hello world', width=20, command=func1)
B.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

C = tk.Button(root, text='hello', width=20, command=func2)
C.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Just declare coords outside the function